# concatenate strings using common identifier

Tags: r

```
s1 <- "A*01 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC"
s2 <- "A*01 TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC"
s3 <- "A*01 TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG"
```

How to concatenate these strings using the identifier "A*01"?

Expected output:

```
sT <- "A*01 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG"
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `paste` or `paste0` are the primary string concatenation workhorses in R. I'm not sure what you mean by "using the identifier A*01".

Comment: first element in the strings is the identifier

Comment: just edited including expected output

Comment: is there a larger data structure or file that has many lines with `A*01` (and other) prefixes? i.e. should there be a more generic solution that does concatenates based on submitted prefix criteria?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your reply answers my question, but I need a more general solution. I have a large data set and the identifiers are of the format "A*\d", where \d are digits.

Comment: Can you post some additional raw lines from the file (with a mixture of those prefixes) and what R data structure you're holding them in? If you haven't decided on the data structure, just the lines would be enough to help you out with a more generic solution.

Comment: The structure is a vector of strings (length: 41264). Identifiers are actually of the kind "A*01:01:01:01", "A*01:01:01:02N", "A*33:29"... There's one identifier per string. There are about 16 strings with each identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more generic solution, I'm assuming you've got a file with a bunch of lines that look like the ones in the question. If that's the case, then the following should give you what you need.

```
library(stringr)
library(plyr)

dat <- readLines(textConnection("A*01 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC
A*01 TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC
A*01 TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG
A*02 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC
A*02 TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC
A*02 TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG
A*03 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC
A*04 TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC
A*04 TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG"))


dat.df <- data.frame(prefix=str_match(dat, "(^A\\*[0-9]+) ")[,2],
                     sequence=str_match(dat, "\ (.*)$")[,2], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

res <- daply(dat.df, .(prefix), .fun=function(x) {
  return(paste(x[1,]$prefix, paste(x$sequence, sep=" ", collapse=" "), 
               sep=" ", collapse=""))
})

names(res) <- NULL

print(res)

## [1] "A*01 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG"
## [2] "A*02 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG"
## [3] "A*03 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC"              
## [4] "A*04 TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG"
```

Comment: just remember to replace the `textConnection(…)` bit with the filename :-)

Comment: Hi hrbmstr, these regex are killing me. What if the identifiers were of the kind "A*01:01:01:01", "A*01:01:01:02", "A*01:01:01:02N", "A*03:01:01:01"... how do I change the regex "(^A\\*[0-9]+) " to match this?

Comment: regexes are often an arcane magic incantation. For those, "(^A\\*[0-9\\:]+) " should work. I may need to put this into the answer since the double escapes seem to be lost in comments).

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub(" A\\*01 ", " ", paste(s1, s2, s3, sep=" ", collapse=""))
```

will do what you want it to do in this case, but I suspect you might need a more generic solution in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
> concat <- paste(s1, sub("A[*]01 ", "", s2), sub("A[*]01 ", "", s3))
> identical(sT, concat)
[1] TRUE
```

`concat` looks like this

```
> concat
[1] "A*01 ATG GCC GTC ATG GCG CCC CGA ACC CTC CTC CTG CTA CTC TCG GGG GCC CTG GCC TCC CAC TCC ATG AGG TAT TTC TTC ACA TCC GTG TCC CCC GGC CGC GGG GAG CCC TAC GTG GAC GAC ACG CAG TTC GTG CGG TTC GAC AGC GAC GCC GCG AGC CAG AAG"
```